# Angular won't apply object changes to it's properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have an object like this:

```
$scope.user = {key: 'j16er48', name: 'Foo', title: 'Bar'}
```

And the template is:

```
<div ng-if="user.key">{{user.name}}</div>
```

Now, if I change the value of `key` property to `null` or `false` directly, then the `div` won't be displayed. But If I change the whole object to this:

```
$scope.user = {key: false, name: 'Foo', title: 'Bar'}
```

Nothing happens. Angular seems to still watch the old object and the old value of `key` property.

I also tried to use `$scope.$apply()` after assigning a new object to `user` but still no chance.

Am I missing something?

== **UPDATE** ==

After so much tests I found a very strange behavior in Angular scope. The issue happens due to an unwanted assignment by reference (or a two-way binding maybe).

I have an object called `defaultUser` which is : `{key: false, name: 'Foo', title: 'Bar'}`. Assuming this:

```
var defaultUser = {key: false, name: null, title: null};

$scope.user = defaultUser;

// here I change a property of $scope.user
$scope.user.key = 'j16er48';

$scope.resetUser = function(){
    // Now defaultUser.key equals 'j16er48'
    alert(defaultUser.key);

    // That's why this line does nothing
    $scope.user = defaultUser;
}
```

So when I tried to assign `defaultUser` to `user` object again, I thought is has been reset, whereas `defaultUser` has been changed and is equal to `user`. right now.

Is that normal? Does Angular assume all assignments by reference? Is that a two-way binding? Have I been crazy or what else?

https://jsfiddle.net/amraei/g1b5xomz/3/

Comment: Something must be wrong with your code. Can you isolate it and post it in a plunker?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: Made a fiddle of what I think you're trying to do : https://jsfiddle.net/g1b5xomz/

Comment: @Rob most likely it's a scope inheritance issue in Omid's case

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an old version of Angular.

I've created two Fiddles, the first is using Angular 1.1.1 (https://jsfiddle.net/dcg74epp/) and the second using Angular 1.2.1 (https://jsfiddle.net/6vy4jn6q/).

They both have a very minimal controller and don't follow any style guidelines, but should get your point across.

```
app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.user = {key: 'j16er48', name: 'Foo', title: 'Bar'};
  var secondUser = {key: false, name: 'Foo', title: 'Bar'};
  var tmp;

  $scope.changeUser = function () {
    tmp = $scope.user;
    $scope.user = secondUser;
    secondUser = tmp;
  };
});
```

So, if using a newer version of Angular is possible for you, use it.